# Filter SharePoint 2010 datasheet view based on currentusergroups out of box

Tags: 2010, datasheet, out-of-the-box

Please help if there is a solution out of box in SharePoint 2010, which helps filter datasheet view on currentusergroup.

Through sharepoint designer, it is doable to change CAML

```
<Query>
 <Where>
   <Or>
   <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/><Value Type="Integer">
    <UserID Type="Integer"/></Value>
   </Eq>
    <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
    </Membership>
  </Or>
</Where>
</Query>
```

http://sharepointcodes.com/filter-list-view-by-user-and-groups-in-sharepoint/

However this is not out of the box, and since SPD is disabled in moss 2010, it cannot be used.

I am asking if there is out of the box solution where you can set code in the browser?

Comment: Please update your question with a full description of the problem and what you have already attempted. The link you provided is good extra info, but if the link breaks in future, your question will be rendered meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQuery with SPServices(spservices.codeplex.com), it uses a CAML query to return results. Your script can be added to the page using a text document uploaded to any library and then called via the content editor web part.

Comment: Thanks Aboba, I would like to try it! If possible, could you please help with a concrete example with datasheet list view?

Comment: It's not going to be using datasheet list view. SPServices is going to return the results as an xml object which you will then need to modify to whatever you want to output on the screen.

Comment: if you can use SPD, the trick is to change WHERE clause in the <ListViewXml...> tag. Is this not possible on the fly as well? Datasheet is prefered as users could then mass change items in the filtered list if necessary.

Comment: Aboba, thanks, I read some documentation and could find out how it works. SPServices is a great tool, it did the trick.